# Injective derivative implies locally injective function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am working on a proof for my real analysis class, and got stuck.

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuously differentiable map, and further suppose that $Df(x_0)$ is injective for some $x_0 \in U$.

Show that there exists an open set $U_1 \subset U$ containing $x_0$ such that $f$ restricted to $U_1$ is injective.

I have already shown that for $x, y, x_0 \in U$, we have that $||f(x) - f(y) - Df(x_0)(x-y)|| \leq ||x-y||\sup||Df(v)-Df(x_0)||$ (*) by using the mean value inequality. Here I am taking the supremum over $v$, where $v$ is in the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$.

I was given a hint to apply this inequality to show that for some open ball $B_r (x_0)$, we have that $||f(x_1) - f(x_2)|| \geq C||x_1 - x_2||$ (**) for some constant $C$.

It is clear to me that injectivity follows from the second inequality (**), but I am struggling to show that this inequality is true.

The injectivity of $Df(x_0)$ gives us that $Df(x_0)(x-y) \neq 0$ for $x \neq y$, and I tried using this fact to break up the left hand side of (*) by, e.g., using the triangle inequality, but was unable to make much progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider 
$$c=\inf_{|v|=1} |Df(x_0)v|.$$
Since $L$ is injective one has $c>0$.

Now from (*), in a neighborhood of $x_0$ where $||Df(x)-Df(x_0)||<c/2$
you get
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\ge |Df(x_0)(x-y)| -  \frac{c}{2}|x-y| \ge \frac{c}{2}|x-y|.
$$

Comment: Could you give some more details on why the inequality in the last line is true? I have been trying to manipulate (*) but haven't made much progress.

Comment: reverse triangle inequality: $|x-y|< a $ implies $|x| > |y|-a$.